# NSMenuItem focus/rollover notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

i would like to respond to focus/rollover action from NSMenuItem, i didn't found any notifications.

How can i achive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign a delegate to the item's parent menu, and implement the following method:

```
- (void)menu:(NSMenu *)menu willHighlightItem:(NSMenuItem *)item
```

Comment: And can you shade a light on click :?

Comment: You can either assign an action to the menu item, or you can bind its value to something.

Comment: Where did you find above method ? I've searched on apple page but couldn't find it :(

Comment: Part of the [NSMenuDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Comment: Hmmm... my last stupid questions will be where can i check to which protocol Class conforms to as on: "http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html" i couldn't find such information.

Comment: Any class can conform to any protocol. If a class uses a special delegate protocol it will be listed in the Overview section or the delegate instance method section.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at -[NSMenuItem setView:]. You can set an NSMenuItem so it has a custom view. You should be able to write a custom NSView subclass that notifies your controller class (via notifications or delegate methods, or whatever) of mouseover events. Then set your NSMenuItem(s) to use instances of your NSView subclass.

Note that if you take this approach, your custom view will also be responsible for drawing the menu item, including title, state, etc. So you'll have some work to do to make the menu item look and behave like a standard menu item...

Comment: Yeap, i know this workaround, but i thought that cocoa provide more friendly way :) Thanks.